# How to make alsactl store persistent?

Tags: audio, alsa

I do

```
aplay test.wav #Fails
sudo amixer cset numid=3 2
aplay test.wav #Works
```

followed by `sudo alsactl store`

However, after reboot I have to repeat

Comment: I guess `alsactl restore` is not run, or some other tool changes the mixer settings afterwards.

Comment: You can store them in desired file like `alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state store` and restore them `alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state restore`

Comment: How to make it persistent once and forever without repeating *restore* every boot?